# How to define HSQ DB properties in Spring JPA using annoations

Tags: spring, jpa, annotations, hsqldb

I am running HSQL DB as a Im memory using run manger Swing.I have to connect the HSQLDB server from Spring JPA repository using annotations.
My repository class.

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface Vehicle extends JpaRepository<Vehicle , BigInteger>{
    public List<Vehicle > findAll(Sort sort);

}
```

service Method:
@Service

```
public class LocationService {

        @Autowired
       VehicletRepository vehicleRepository = null;

        /**
         * This method is to get all the locations from the repository
         */
        public List<Vehicle> getVehicless() {
            Order order = new Order(Direction.ASC,"vehicleCode");
            Sort sort = new Sort(order);
            List<Airport> airports = vehicletRepository .findAll(sort);
            System.out.println("inside service");

            return vehicles;
        }     

    }
```

Anyone help to achieve Spring JPA conenction with HSQL DB using annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you dont use Spring boot:

you need @Configuration class -(it basically is new way to configure spring applications in java ) with  @EnableJpaRepositories which turn it spring data jpa/ spring data rest for you. You will also have to specify your entity manager, transaction manager and data source beans. Example below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("your.package.with.repositories")
public class DBConfig{
 @Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    DBConfigurationCommon.configureDB(dataSource, your_jdbc_url_here, db_username_here, db_password_here);
    return dataSource;
}
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

    //you may need to define new Properties(); here with hibernate dialect and add it to entity manager factory
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("your_package_with_domain_classes_here");

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}
}
```